# Stop showing ad for 15 seconds after user clicks on it Facebook Audience Network

Tags: java, android, facebook-audience-network, facebook-monetization-manager

I have implemented facebook audience network banner ad in my android app. I want to not the ad for 15 seconds after user clicks on it and returns to the app. I have searched a lot and can not find any solution.I am doing this to prevent illegal clicks. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an Ad Listener and override the `onAdClicked` clicked method and do the stuff you want to do [Here is the facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/setting-up/ad-setup/android/banner/)
on how set an Ad Listener

Comment: I think facebook has removed ```onAdClicked``` meyhod for banner ads. In android studio only 3 methods are showing.